# Vulkan calculation of Barycentric coordinates? Is area function 2D or 3D?

Tags: vulkan

In section 25.8.1 Basic Polygon Rasterization of the Vulkan spec it says:

> Barycentric coordinates are a set of three numbers, a, b, and c, each in the range [0,1], with a + b + c
> = 1. These coordinates uniquely specify any point p within the triangle or on the triangle’s
> boundary as
>
> ```
> p = a * p_a + b * p_b + c * p_c
> ```
>
> where p_a , p_b , and p_c are the vertices of the triangle. a, b, and c are determined by:
>
> ```
> a = A(p, p_b, p_c) / A(p_a, p_b, p_c)
> b = A(p, p_a, p_c) / A(p_a, p_b, p_c)
> c = A(p, p_a, p_b) / A(p_a, p_b, p_c)
> ```
>
> where `A(l,m,n)` denotes **the area in framebuffer coordinates** of the triangle with vertices l, m, and n.

Framebuffer coordinates technically have three components.  This is specified in 24.5 Controlling the Viewport as:

> The vertex’s framebuffer coordinates (x_f , y_f , z_f ) are given by [snip]

**What precisely is the formula of the `A` function?**

Is it either:

(a) the same as the formula given to calculate whether the triangle is back-facing or front-facing in 25.8.1, namely:

> ```
> a = -0.5 * sum_i(x_f[i] * y_f[i+1] - x_f[i+1] * y_f[i])
> ```

That is, is it taken as read that the forumla of `A` does not use the `z_f` components of its arguments, and is purely a function of the `(x_f, y_f)` components?  (ie It is calculating the area of the two dimensional projection of the triangle onto the x-y plane in framebuffer-space)

or (b), does `A` use all three framebuffer components? ie Does `A` return the area of the triangle in the full three-dimensional framebuffer-space (like shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1951650/22933) for example)

or (c) something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually doesn't matter, mathematically speaking. Whichever function you pick, you'll find that the particulars of the math divide out when computing the barycentric coordinate.

A barycentric coordinate is computed by taking the ratio of two areas. If you linearly project two co-planar triangles from 3D space to 2D space with the same projection, the ratio of their areas is unchanged (assuming that they have an area post-projection).